# Merging two datasets with different dates/UNIX timestamps

Tags: charts, dataset, chart.js

I'm trying to make a chart that shows the trade volumes for the currencies CAD and DKK:

https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/g7mht8tt/

Using data from these files:

- http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcCAD.csv.gz
- http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcDKK.csv.gz

But, how do I deal with the fact that these datasets have different dates/UNIX timestamps? My chart above has DKK's data "forced into" CAD's timestamps -- but this can't be right can it? What should I do?

Note: The below snippet doesn't have the full data due to StackOverflow's body limit.

```js
// Disable pointers
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.hoverRadius = 0;

var myChartData = {
  // Timestamps from http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcCAD.csv.gz
  labels: [1363085391, 1363088879, 1363120475, 1363132522, 1363214378],

  // Timestamps from http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcDKK.csv.gz
  //labels: [1366383202, 1366471506, 1368121200, 1375783458, 1375953845],
  datasets: [{
    label: "CAD",
    borderColor: "#FF0000",
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [5.432200000000, 4.981800000000, 1.768000000000, 1.000000000000, 4.000000000000]
  },
  {
    label: "DKK",
    borderColor: "#000000",
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [1.000000000000, 2.700000000000, 2.187400000000, 1.000000000000, 4.000000000000]
  }
  ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("mychart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: myChartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        ticks: {
          minRotation: 90
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/chartjs/chartjs.github.io/master/dist/master/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="mychart"></canvas>
```

Comment: maybe add two diff. x-axis..?

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Thanks!

Comment: something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY2b9.png) ?